# Android all kinds of errors from Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

What is going on with Gradle and Kotlin? I haven't even started coding yet, and already regretting getting back on Android :(

Gradle project

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shivaapps.liftingboard"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.21.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Error logs

```
e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\u0014\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\u0018\u0000 \u00052\u00020\u0001:\u0001\u0005B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\b\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004H\u0016\u00a8\u0006\u0006"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardApplication;", "Landroid/app/Application;", "()V", "onCreate", "", "Companion", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardComponent.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\u0016\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\bg\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001J\u0010\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u00032\u0006\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0005H&\u00a8\u0006\u0006"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardComponent;", "", "inject", "", "application", "Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardApplication;", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardApplication.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e:     @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\u0014\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0005\b\u0086\u0003\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0007\b\u0002\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002R\u001a\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004X\u0086.\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0005\u0010\u0006\"\u0004\b\u0007\u0010\b\u00a8\u0006\t"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardApplication$Companion;", "", "()V", "graph", "Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardComponent;", "getGraph", "()Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardComponent;", "setGraph", "(Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardComponent;)V", "app_debug"})
e:            ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardModule.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\u0018\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\b\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\r\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0004J\b\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u0003H\u0007J\b\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u0007H\u0007R\u000e\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003X\u0082\u0004\u00a2\u0006\u0002\n\u0000\u00a8\u0006\b"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardModule;", "", "application", "Landroid/app/Application;", "(Landroid/app/Application;)V", "provideApplicationContext", "provideLiftingBoardService", "Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/LiftingBoardService;", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/LiftingBoardService.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\n\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\bf\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001\u00a8\u0006\u0002"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/LiftingBoardService;", "", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/models/Exercise.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\u0012\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0006\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0015\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0003\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0005R\u0011\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u00a2\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0006\u0010\u0007R\u0011\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0003\u00a2\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\b\u0010\u0007\u00a8\u0006\t"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/models/Exercise;", "", "id", "", "name", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V", "getId", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "getName", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/pages/LoginActivity.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000B\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0005\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0005\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\b\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\u0010\u0010\u000f\u001a\u00020\u00102\u0006\u0010\u0011\u001a\u00020\u0012H\u0002J\"\u0010\u0013\u001a\u00020\u00102\u0006\u0010\u0014\u001a\u00020\u00152\u0006\u0010\u0016\u001a\u00020\u00152\b\u0010\u0017\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0018H\u0014J\u0012\u0010\u0019\u001a\u00020\u00102\b\u0010\u001a\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u001bH\u0014J\b\u0010\u001c\u001a\u00020\u0010H\u0014J\b\u0010\u001d\u001a\u00020\u0010H\u0002R\u001a\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004X\u0086.\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0005\u0010\u0006\"\u0004\b\u0007\u0010\bR\u001a\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\nX\u0086.\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u000b\u0010\f\"\u0004\b\r\u0010\u000e\u00a8\u0006\u001e"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/pages/LoginActivity;", "Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;", "()V", "callBAckManager", "Lcom/facebook/CallbackManager;", "getCallBAckManager", "()Lcom/facebook/CallbackManager;", "setCallBAckManager", "(Lcom/facebook/CallbackManager;)V", "firebaseAuth", "Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth;", "getFirebaseAuth", "()Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth;", "setFirebaseAuth", "(Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth;)V", "handleFacebookAccessToken", "", "accessToken", "Lcom/facebook/AccessToken;", "onActivityResult", "requestCode", "", "resultCode", "data", "Landroid/content/Intent;", "onCreate", "savedInstanceState", "Landroid/os/Bundle;", "onStart", "performSuccessAction", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/DatabaseReferenceExtensionKt.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 2, d1 = {"\u0000\u0010\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\u001a\u0012\u0010\u0000\u001a\n\u0012\u0006\u0012\u0004\u0018\u00010\u00020\u0001*\u00020\u0003\u00a8\u0006\u0004"}, d2 = {"observeSingleEvent", "Lrx/Observable;", "Lcom/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot;", "Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/FirebaseDatabaseThrowable.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\u0012\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0003\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0005\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0011\b\u0016\u0012\b\u0010\u0002\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0003\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0004R\u0016\u0010\u0005\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u00018VX\u0096\u0004\u00a2\u0006\u0006\u001a\u0004\b\u0006\u0010\u0007R\u0010\u0010\u0002\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0003X\u0082\u0004\u00a2\u0006\u0002\n\u0000\u00a8\u0006\b"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/FirebaseDatabaseThrowable;", "", "databaseError", "Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError;", "(Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError;)V", "cause", "getCause", "()Ljava/lang/Throwable;", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/FirebaseLiftingBoardService.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 6}, bv = {1, 0, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002\u00a8\u0006\u0003"}, d2 = {"Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/FirebaseLiftingBoardService;", "Lcom/shivaapps/liftingboard/services/LiftingBoardService;", "()V", "app_debug"})
e:        ^
e:   symbol:   class Metadata
e:   location: package kotlin
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardModule.java:5: error: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
e: 

e: public final class LiftingBoardModule {
e:              ^
e: /Users/aryaxt/Repos/LiftingBoard/Android/LiftingBoard/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/shivaapps/liftingboard/LiftingBoardComponent.java:6: error: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
e: 

e: public abstract interface LiftingBoardComponent {
e:                 ^
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:144)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:397)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:798)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:825)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:791)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:364)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:139)
    ... 40 more


 FAILED
```

Comment: Did you try removing `provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`

Comment: I just tired, same error

Comment: Can we see `40 more...` part?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov How do I get that? I tried running with stacktrace or debug, and it's still not printing the full log

Comment: Isn't it clickable?

Comment: no it's not :( missing Xcode already ;)

Comment: Run `gradlew build > logs.txt 2> errors.txt`

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: no Couldn't find out what the problem was, so I started a brand new project and now I don't see the issue again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the Kotlin standard library as a compile dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: I think  it is `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7` for Android

Comment: @Joshua That is optional. stdlib-jre7 adds some extension methods for AutoCloseable, and stdlib-jre8 adds some for the new collections api, but the majority of stdlib is the same no matter which dependency you choose.